# Encoding UTF-16 to UTF-8 C#

Tags: c#

Hello everyone i have some problem with Encoding..
i want convert utf-16 to utf-8 i founded many code but didn't work..
I hope help me.. Thanks

This text =>

'\x04\x1a\x040\x04@\x04B\x040\x00 \x00*\x003\x003\x000\x001\x00:\x00 \x000\x001\x00.\x001\x001\x00.\x002\x000\x002\x002\x00 \x001\x004\x00:\x001\x000\x00,\x00 \x04?\x04>\x04?\x04>\x04;\x04=\x045\x04=\x048\x045\x00 \x003\x003\x00.\x003\x003\x00 \x00T\x00J\x00S\x00.\x00 \x00 \x04\x14\x04>\x04A\x04B\x04C\x04?\x04=\x04>\x00 \x003\x002\x002\x003'

#I tryed this

```
  string v = Regex.Unescape(text);
```

## get result like

♦→♦0♦@♦B♦0 *3301: 01.11.2022 14:10, ♦?♦>♦?♦>♦;♦=♦5♦=♦8♦5 33.33 TJS.  ♦¶♦>♦A♦B♦C♦?♦=♦> 3223

and continue

```
  public static string Utf16ToUtf8(string utf16String)
        {
            // Get UTF16 bytes and convert UTF16 bytes to UTF8 bytes
            byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(utf16String);
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);

            // Return UTF8 bytes as ANSI string
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(utf8Bytes);
        }
```

don't worked

I need result like this

Карта *4411: 01.11.2022 14:10, пополнение 33.33 TJS.  Доступно 3223

Comment: It looks like this is UTF-16, but treated as if it were ASCII with any non-readable ASCII values encoded with `\x`. While we could *speculate* on code to convert that to a string, we'd really need more details of the escaping. Is an ASCII backslash represented as `\\` for example? Where does this data come from, and can you avoid the extra escaping involved?

Comment: Describe how and from where you received such data. Probably the problem can be solved by a higher level. For example, you need to specify the correct encoding when requesting data from a web service.

Comment: honestly, that input is just gibberish; it isn't clear why you expect something that is mostly control characters to output meaningful text; and I'm not seeing ***any*** high bytes (anything over 127), so I wouldn't expect anything in the Russian range - this is all either pure ASCII, mostly control-codes (i.e. 0-31)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This also helped me:

```
string reg = Regex.Unescape(text2);

byte[] ascii = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(reg);
byte[] utf8 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, Encoding.UTF8, ascii);

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(utf8));
```

Comment: Was the original text actually escaped via Regex.Escape or an equivalent? If not, this could very easily do entirely the wrong thing. And fundamentally, the conversions here are mislabeled and wrong...

Answer (score 5):

The code below decodes the text to what you want, but it would be *much* better to avoid getting into this situation in the first place. If the data is fundamentally text, store it as text in your log files without the extra "convert to UTF-16 then encode that binary data" aspect - that's just causing problems.

The code below "decodes" the text log data into a byte array by treating each `\x` escape sequence as a single byte (assuming `\\` is used to encode backslashes) and treating any other character as a single byte - effectively ISO-8859-1.

It then converts the byte array to a string using big-endian UTF-16. The output is as desired:

> Карта *3301: 01.11.2022 14:10, пополнение 33.33 TJS.  Доступно 3223

The code is really inefficient - it's effectively a proof of concept to validate the text format you've got. *Don't use it as-is; instead, use this as a starting point for improving your storage representation.*

```cs
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string logText = @"\x04\x1a\x040\x04@\x04B\x040\x00 \x00*\x003\x003\x000\x001\x00:\x00 \x000\x001\x00.\x001\x001\x00.\x002\x000\x002\x002\x00 \x001\x004\x00:\x001\x000\x00,\x00 \x04?\x04>\x04?\x04>\x04;\x04=\x045\x04=\x048\x045\x00 \x003\x003\x00.\x003\x003\x00 \x00T\x00J\x00S\x00.\x00 \x00 \x04\x14\x04>\x04A\x04B\x04C\x04?\x04=\x04>\x00 \x003\x002\x002\x003";

        byte[] utf16 = DecodeLogText(logText);
        string text = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(utf16);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }

    static byte[] DecodeLogText(string logText)
    {
        List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
        for (int i = 0; i < logText.Length; i++)
        {
            if (logText[i] == '\\')
            {
                if (i == logText.Length - 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Trailing backslash");
                }
                switch (logText[i + 1])
                {
                    case 'x':
                        if (i >= logText.Length - 3)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Not enough data for \\x escape sequence");
                        }
                        // This is horribly inefficient, but never mind.
                        bytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(logText.Substring(i + 2, 2), 16));
                        // Consume the x and hex
                        i += 3;
                        break;
                    case '\\':
                        bytes.Add((byte) '\\');
                        // Consume the extra backslash
                        i++;
                        break;
                    // TODO: Any other escape sequences?
                    default:
                        throw new Exception("Unknown escape sequence");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bytes.Add((byte) logText[i]);
            }
        }
        return bytes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zero: I really hope you're not just going to take that code and use it. You *really, really* should address the problematic format of your log files instead.

Comment: There's no such thing as "store it as text" without knowing the encoding of the data and the encoding of the storage/log. I personally prefer UTF-8 for everything because there you never need BOM and strings are compatible with all the old C APIs. However, Windows defaults to UTF-16LE for historical reasons (with older software actually accidentally using UCS-2 in little endian format instead).